# Laravel Eloquent WhereBetween with Comma Delimited Timestamps?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, date, eloquent

[image]

Given the image above... using Laravel's Eloquent - how could I lookup a specific date range to return the rows that are within that range?

I know Laravel has a whereBetween function that works with conventional date fields, but since these are timestamps, I realize I'd have to use something along the lines of `where('dates', '>=', $startTimestamp)` and `where('dates', '<=', $endTimestamp)` but I'd also have to have that apply to each date exploded from the column?

Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: I think you've built your database wrong...

Comment: What is the data type of your dates column?

Comment: Having dates in a text field as CSV is probably the wrong approach. You might want to look into using a pivot of some kind, or a JSON column. As it stands, you're gonna have a hard time getting specific records based on that column, especially if you're going to rely on php's `explode()` function; requires getting every record before you can filter them.

Comment: I have utilised a jquery datepicker that reads this format back in JSON, that is why I initially went with the approach of saving timestamps delimited.

Comment: Rather than totally rebuilding it, I'm looking to possibly use mysql to create temp tables to lookup from, rather than php exploding...

Comment: You should use a native `datetime` or `timestamp` type for each individual value in the database. Otherwise you'll also lose access to all the useful methods used to query such columns and also native functions will work with (by far) reduced performance. Splitting in PHP is a lot less work than you'll have later on when you continue with this schema design. Even creating a view like you suggested is more work than changing the schema, at least in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the fact that it may be poor database setup, sometimes things just have to be done the way they are currently done - for business reasons or tardiness or whatever else; an unsightly fix can be better than a total overhaul - especially in cases where a system is small and will remain small, not requiring overthought on processing speeds.

Here is a solution to the proposed question, utilising MySQL table joinings, selecting from that joining response. This is also written in Laravel, hence the DB static function.

```
$temp = DB::select(DB::raw("select
  leave_entries.id,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(leave_entries.dates, ',', numbers.n), ',', -1) dates
  from
  (select 1 n union all
   select 2 union all select 3 union all
   select 4 union all select 5) numbers INNER JOIN leave_entries
  on CHAR_LENGTH(leave_entries.dates)
     -CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(leave_entries.dates, ',', ''))>=numbers.n-1
     where uid = {$uid}
     AND dates >= {$start_timestamp} 
     AND dates <= {$end_timestamp}
  order by
  id, n"));

// Return the resulting table:
dd($temp);
```

Leaving this here instead of deleting the question, since it may help someone.

Future person: in your case - if you can redo the database schema instead, as the comments to my question suggested, then do so.